# How to prove that this cartesian product of subspaces is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Let $l_0<l_1<l_2<l_3\in \mathbb{R}$, $I_1=(l_0,l_1),\, I_2=(l_1,l_2)$ and $I_3=(l_2,l_3)$. Define the spaces

\begin{equation*}
H^2_{l_0}=\{u\in H^2(I_1):u(l_0)=u'(l_0)=0\}\\
H^2_{l_3}=\{w\in H^2(I_3):w(l_3)=w'(l_3)=0\}
\end{equation*}
whit the following inner products
\begin{equation*}
\left<u,\hat{u}\right>_{H^2_{l_0}}=\left<u'',\hat{u}''\right>_{L^2(I_1)}\\
\left<w,\hat{w}\right>_{H^2_{l_3}}=\left<w'',\hat{w}''\right>_{L^2(I_3)}
\end{equation*}
then, the space

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{H}:=\{(u,v,w)\in H^2_{l_0}\times H^1(I_2)\times H^2_{l_3}:u(l_1)=v(l_1) \text{ and } v(l_2)=w(l_2)\}
\end{equation*}

is closed due to the continuity of the **trace operator**.

I have already proven that both $H^2_{l_0}$ and $H^2_{l_3}$ are closed. But I don't know how the trace operator is used to prove the rest.

Can somebody give me a hand with this?

Comment: Do you already know that the mappings $u\mapsto u(l_1), v\mapsto v(l_1), v\mapsto v(l_2)$ and $w\mapsto w(l_2)$ are continuous? If yes, then your set is the kernel of a continuous linear map and hence closed.

Comment: We can consider $$ F: H^2_{l_0}\times H^1(I_2)\times H^2_{l_3} \mapsto \mathbb{C}^2, (u,v,w)\mapsto (u(l_1)-v(l_1), v(l_2)-w(l_2))$$ then $\mathbb{H}=F^{-1}(\{(0,0)\})$. Hence, if we can show that $F$ is continuous, we are done. So we only need to know the continuity of the maps in my previous comment.